# Receiving error code value from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm sure, that's an easy question, but I have real obscuration in mind and can't find a solution.

I have an extremely simple xml, which looks like:

```
  <xml-header>
   <error code="40" message="errorMessage" /> 
  </xml-header>
```

And I need to get value "40" from it. So, in my opinion that means: get value from attribute "code" of element "error". (Am I right?)

```
return (from node in xdoc.Descendants() select node.Element("error").Attribute("code").Value).First();
```

And that doesn't work. What's the correct expression?

---

[update]

Sorry everyone, the problem was with xNamespace.

So it should be like: `xdoc.Descendants(Constants.xNamespace)` *even had this one in Constants class, aarrgh.*

Comment: "doesn't work" == do you have exception? or the result is different what you have expected ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select descendant *error* elements. Also avoid to use Value property, if you don't want to get an exception if there is no such attribute in element:

```
(from node in xdoc.Descendants("error") 
 select (int)node.Attribute("code"))
 .First();
```

You can also use method syntax:

```
xdoc.Descendants("error")
    .Select(e => (int)e.Attribute("code"))
    .First()
```

Keep in mind - First will throw an exception if sequence does not contain elements. If you want to avoid that error, use `FirstOrDefault` instead. If there is namespace defined, then use it when selecting elements:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://someAdress";
xdoc.Descendants(ns + "error")
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it. And now I have "sequence contains no elements".

Comment: @Olter thats what I wrote in `Keep in mind` part :) Looks like you don't have `error` elements in your xml. Are you sure there is no *namespace* defined?

Comment: Damn it! How did I miss that? And, the most stupid thing, that I've written that namespace in the question update, but for some reason it wasn't printed. Thanks.

Comment: @Olter I've added sample on namespaces usage in Linq :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (all error handling omitted!):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<xml-header><error code=\"40\" message=\"errorMessage\" /></xml-header>";

            var element = XElement.Load(new StringReader(xml));
            var errorElement = element.XPathSelectElement("error");
            string code = errorElement.Attribute("code").Value;

            Console.WriteLine(code); // Prints 40
        }
    }
}
```

Or, using XDocument and avoiding extensions:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<xml-header><error code=\"40\" message=\"errorMessage\" /></xml-header>";

            var doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml));

            var errorElement = doc.Element("xml-header").Element("error");
            string code = errorElement.Attribute("code").Value;

            Console.WriteLine(code);  // Prints 40
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm working with Windows-Phone, and it seems, that there is no _XPathSelectElement_ method in its framework. And I need a solution for XDocument object, don't want to cast/parse it from string.

Comment: I appended to my answer a version that works with XDocument and avoids extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

You already have `error` element in descendants.
Try this:

```
return xdoc.Descendants().Select(n => n.Attribute("code").Value).First();
```

or this, if you like query style:

```
return (from node in xdoc.Descendants() select node.Attribute("code").Value).First();
```

Comment: Actually, I have NullReferenceException both in my own expression and yours.

Comment: @Olter Look at [this](https://compilr.com/hamlet/test5/main.cs). What's the problem with this code?